# Show x recent posts on Wordpress with title, date and excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to find a way to show the last 5 posts on the homepage of my Wordpress website, so i assume i will need to utilise shortcodes to do this, however i cannot find any pre-existing code to add to functions.php that will show the title, date and post excerpt.

Could someone possibly help me with this?

Comment: Is this a custom theme? If it is, then you can just control The Loop to only run five times...Otherwise, you're kind of stuck with how they designed it...

Comment: No, it's the standard twentyeleven that i'm re-designing for a client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this, but the basic idea is similar to the code you'll see in your theme's **INDEX.PHP** page. You do a query, loop through to show the posts, then reset the query at the end so what you did doesn't interfere with your main page.

```
function Last5posts()
{
    $args = array( "showposts" => 5 );                  
    query_posts($args);

    $content = "";

    if( have_posts() ) : 

        while( have_posts() ) :

            the_post();
            $link = get_permalink();
            $title = get_the_title();
            $date = get_the_date();                              

            $content .= "<div style='padding: 5px; border: 1px solid red'>";
            $content .= "<h3><a href='$link' target='_top'>$title / $date</a></h3>\n";
            $content .= "<p class='excerpt'>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p>";
            $content .= "</div>";

        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();

    endif;

    // Leave one line commented out depending on usage
    echo $content;   // For use as widget
    //return $content; // for use as shortcode
}
```

To register this as a widget, enable the "echo" at the end, then add this line to the bottom of your file:

```
register_sidebar_widget(__('Last 5 Posts'), 'Last5posts');
```

You may want to add some extra code to place the output into a widget wrapper DIV like your other sidebar widgets. (Or, not if you use it somewhere besides a traditional sidebar.)

You could also register this as a shortcode handler using the line below. Comment out the "echo" at the end and uncomment the "return".

```
add_shortcode('Last5Posts', 'Last5posts' );
```

You'll want to make sure that you don't use the shortcode in blog posts or you might end up calling this recursively. Probably a bad thing.

You'll probably also want to add a theme-specific prefix to the function name to avoid namespace collisions.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this worked almost perfectly (it's exactly what i wanted). For some reason the posts show at the top of the page instead of where it's supposed to display, i.e. at the bottom of the page. Any ideas? I also placed the shortcode inside a div, however the div is no longer appearing.

Comment: The posts will simply show inline wherever the sidebar with the widget is located. If you want the widget elsewhere you'll have to either put it into a different sidebar or edit your CSS to change where things are located.

Comment: I used the shortcode as opposed to the widget, it appears i have to "return" as opposed to use "echo" in order to display the shortcode where i want on the page as opposed to the top of the page, however when i changed echo to return, the shortcode stopped working. Me and PHP don't go together, is there any chance you know how to solve this final issue?

Comment: Using a shortcode means you're wanting the content produced by the shortcode to be inline with the surrounding text. Whatever you do with a shortcode is logically constrained to the DIV the post is contained in. (Unless you're doing something really, really wrong.)

I suspect that what you're doing might make more sense if you used a custom page template which adds a sidebar where you want this content to appear. Keep in mind that sidebars aren't something that have to appear on every page, and using custom page templates can give you endless opportunity for customizing the layout as needed.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot about the "return" needed for being a shortcode. If that's what you need, just change "echo" to "return". However, the other stuff I said in the previous comment may still apply.

Comment: I tried what you just suggested above before and it didn't work, guess i did something wrong. It's now working perfectly as i wanted it - thanks a lot for your time Mike, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    $args = array('numberposts' => 5);

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
      echo $recent["post_title"].' '.$recent['post_date'].' '.$recent['post_excerpt'].'<br />';
    }
?>
```

The [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) isn't that bad.

Comment: Thanks for that, however as i'm not well versed with PHP, i'm not entirely sure how i add this to my functions.php. I added the obvious functions, then the code above minus the php tags, and also add_shortcode, however i get unexpected $end for the add_shortcode line.

Comment: So the code looked like; function show_the_posts( $atts ){ CODE YOU POSTED ABOVE } then below that was add_sortcode etc

Comment: I cannot say what your error line looks like. Please edit the code in, or better link to a file or fiddle if it's too much.

Comment: Don't know if you just forgot it in the txt, but there is the php-endtag "?>" missing, This matches the errormessage.

Comment: It would have been nice to know if it worked after correcting this simple error, but one cannot have everything....

Comment: Hi sorry, i tried it with the ?> and it didn't appear to fix the issue.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the Featured Image of the post in this way?